# How to play mkv files on ChromeOS?

Tags: video, google-chrome-os, matroska

How can I play MKV files on ChromeOS?

I have a lot of videos in MKV format on my local network available over NFS/SMB? How can I get them to play, **without transcoding**, on a ChromeOS machine?

Comment: Have you tried looking for MPlayer or Mplayer2, some people claim that they have VLC working in Chrome OS.

Comment: Thanks all, doesn't look like theres any good solution yet but thanks for the ideas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some people report that renaming the files from .mkv to .mp4 is enough. Worth trying.

If this doesn't work, the only solution I can think of is converting the files to another format.

[source](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/chromebook-central/G1ECCeIecsE)

Comment: mkv is not the same as mp4.

Comment: @ColeJohnson: mkv and mp4 are both containers for video, itself encoded using a codec. All I can say is that this trick has worked for some people, but of course may not work for the specific video files of the OP.

Answer (score 4):

You might be able to get VLC to work. See https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/chromebook-central/SjJqx5nO_Sc

Apparently, Jolicloud for Chrome might work. Not sure though. Here's the app. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jolicloud/nfakdllpdfjjbfommlcnfkedmbigkfdo/details

Unfortunately, VLC requires a lot of work to get going. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that it currently can be done universally without transcoding -- MKV is a container format and can house many different video/audio codecs (some of which are supported by ChromeOS and some are not).  For those video formats that *are* supported I have had luck simply switching containers (from MKV to MP4) using ffmpeg.  This preserves the original video (that is, does *not* transcode) but changes the container.